# Log parsing rules in Jenkins

Tags: regex, gcc, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm using Jenkins log parser plugin to extract and display the build log.
The rule file looks like,

```
 # Compiler Error
 error /(?i) error:/

 # Compiler Warning
 warning /(?i) warning:/
```

Everything works fine but for some reasons, at the end of "Parsed Output Console", I see this message,

```
NOTE: Some bad parsing rules have been found:

Bad parsing rule: , Error:1
Bad parsing rule: , Error:1
```

This, I'm sure is a trivial issue but not able to figure it out at this moment.
Please help :)

**EDIT:**
Based on Kobi's answer and having looked into the ["Parsing rules files"](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin), I fixed it this way (a single space after colon). This worked perfectly as expected.

```
# Compiler Error
error /(?i)error: /

# Compiler Warning
warning /(?i)warning: /
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) does not support spaces in your pattern.

This can be clearly seen in their [source code](https://svn.jenkins-ci.org/trunk/hudson/plugins/log-parser/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/logparser/LogParserUtils.java):

```
final String ruleParts[] = parsingRule.split("\\s");
String regexp = ruleParts[1];
```

They should probably have used [`.split("\\s", 2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

As an alternative, you can use `\s`, `\b`, or an [escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Escape_sequences) - `\u0020`.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried no spaces in the pattern, but that did not work.
Turns out that the Parsing Rules files does not support
empty lines in it. Once I removed the empty lines, I did not
get this "Bad parsing rule: , Error:1".

I think since the line is empty - it doesn't echo any rule after
the first colon. Would have been nice it the line number was
reported where the problem is.