# Seeing Bad parsing rule for Jenkins Log parser plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) with Jenkins. Following is my rule file which I have taken from the sample given on the link.

```
# match line starting with 'error', case-insensitive
error /(?i)^error/

# list of warnings here...
warning /[Ww]arning/
warning /WARNING/

# create a quick access link to lines in the report containing 'INFO'
info /INFO/

# each line containing 'BUILD' represents the start of a section for grouping errors and warnings found after the line.
# also creates a quick access link.
start /BUILD/
```

I still see following at the end of the `Parsed Console Output` page:

```
NOTE: Some bad parsing rules have been found:
Bad parsing rule: , Error:1
Bad parsing rule: , Error:1
Bad parsing rule: , Error:1
```

I did come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142768/log-parsing-rules-in-jenkins), but dint help as I am not using space anywhere.

Can someone help me resolving this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you have extra white-space somewhere in the file that the plugin is interpreting as you attempting to define a rule. Maybe try running it with the empty lines removed. That plugin has given me quite a bit of trouble as well, it's not very well documented (as is the case with many Jenkins plugins).

Comment: Glad I could help ! I've been working with Jenkins a lot recently, lots of little quirks and intricacies with these plugins haha

Comment: Smartness level = sky-high. Thanks so much. Life saver.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried no spaces in the pattern, but that did not work. Turns out that the Parsing Rules files does not support empty lines in it. Once I removed the empty lines, I did not get this "Bad parsing rule: , Error:1".

I think since the line is empty - it doesn't echo any rule after the first colon. Would have been nice it the line number was reported where the problem is.

I posted the same to this thread too - [Log parsing rules in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142768/log-parsing-rules-in-jenkins#51640284)

Hopefully, it helps out other folks who may be wondering what is causing this.